# When I use Repository interface in Spring Data JPA what happens under the hood?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have simple Spring Boot application.

And when I use Spring Data JPA I'm confused. Because I don't understand all this magic.

Ok, magic comes with Spring in runtime. But what exactly is happening there?

We just create proxy object for UserRepository interface and generate code for `User findByLoginName(String loginName)` method?

**Can you please describe with details what happens under the hood in Spring Data JPA?**

Entity object `User.java`:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String loginName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String pwd;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean enabled;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

Repository interface `UserRepository.java`:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByLoginName(String loginName);
}
```

Usage our `UserRepository` in `UserController.java`:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
        final User user = userRepository.findByLoginName(id);
        // ...

    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder why you need to know that?

Comment: I have some interest about how Spring works inside.